# Comparing String Arrays Outputs Null

Tags: java, arrays, null

The program outputs a bunch of nulls when comparing. I think I am not comparing correctly, although I have tried == and that outputs nothing. Below is the code and below that is the NameAgeOcc.txt

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class MoreSelectionSortAndParallelArrays
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner inputStream = null;

    try
    {
        inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("NameAgeOcc.txt"));
    }

    catch(FileNotFoundException error)
    {
        System.out.println("Unable to open input file.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    int length=inputStream.nextInt();
    int ages [] = new int[length];
    String names [] = new String[length];
    String occupations [] = new String[length];
    String junk= inputStream.nextLine() ;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        names[i]=inputStream.nextLine();
        ages[i]=inputStream.nextInt();
        junk=inputStream.nextLine();
        occupations[i]=inputStream.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.printf("%-25s%-8s%24s%n","Names","  Ages","Occupations");
    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%-25s%6d%24s%n",names[i],ages[i],occupations[i]);
    }
    String Temp, Temp3;
    int minVal,minPos,y,Temp2;
    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        minVal=ages[i];
        minPos=i;
        for(y=i+1;y<length;y++)
        {
            if(ages[y]<minVal)
            {
                minVal=ages[y];
                minPos=y;
            }
        }
        Temp2 = ages[minPos];
        ages[minPos] = ages[i];
        ages[i] = Temp2;
        Temp = names[minPos];
        names[minPos] = names[i];
        names[i] = Temp;
        Temp3 = occupations[minPos];
        occupations[minPos] = occupations[i];
        occupations[i] = Temp3;
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("%-25s%-8s%24s%n","Names","  Ages","Occupations");
    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
                  System.out.printf("%-25s%6d%24s%n",names[i],ages[i],occupations[i]);
    }
    int studentCount=0;
    for (i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        if(occupations[i].equalsIgnoreCase("student"));
        studentCount++;
    }
    int studentAges [] = new int[studentCount];
    String studentNames [] = new String[studentCount];
    System.out.printf("%-25s%-8s%n","Names","  Ages");

    for (i=0;i<studentCount;i++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%-25s%6d%n",studentNames[i],studentAges[i]);
    }
inputStream.close();
}
}
```

The .txt

```
15
Smith, John
26
Baker
Jones, Susan
15
Student
Mouse, Mickey
31
Theme park employee
Mouse, Mighty
48
Cartoon super hero
Anderson, William
35
Computer Programmer
Parker, Cindy
18
Author
McCain, John
20
Student
Armstrong, Michelle
17
Student
Thompson, Anne
29
Doctor
Li, Steve
15
Student
James, Tanya
20
Student
Moore, James
32
Teacher
Andrews, Julie
75
Actress
Obama, Michelle
46
Lawyer
Michaels, Todd
51
Student
```

*Make sure you copy the empty line at the end of the .txt (hit enter or return)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Program outputs bunch of nulls because you are creating `studentAges` and `studentNames`, but you are not putting something into it.

@Paweł Adamski's answer is incorrect

```java
if(occupations[i].equalsIgnoreCase("student"));
studentCount++;
```

means that you are increasing `studentCount` always.

I would recommend you to use some inner class and than use `Arrays.sort()` for sorting (You have to implement Comparable interface or implements Comparator interface for sorting).

Answer (score 0):

I've check your code briefly and I've found this:

```
if(occupations[i].equalsIgnoreCase("student"));
studentCount++;
```

";" at the end of "if" causes that studentCount is always incremented.

Of course there might be more mistakes in your code. If you want people to help you, you should explain what your program is doing.

Comment: Okay, my program is (at least the part I'm having trouble with) trying to count the students in the occupations array, and then create new arrays, studentNames and studentAges, and then organize studentNames in alphabetical order while keeping studentAges intact.